# How to efficiently compute the maximum for this class of constrained polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, optimization, computer-science, computational-mathematics

\begin{align}
(p_1, p_2, \dots, p_M) = \arg\max_{(q_1,\dots, q_M)} = \sum_{i=1}^M \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^M ( a(i, j)  \cdot q_{j} ) \cdot q_i+ \sum_{k=1}^Nb(i,k) \cdot q_i \right\},
\end{align}
subject to
\begin{align}
 p_i&>0 \quad \text{  for all } i, \\
 p_M &= 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{M-1} p_i.
\end{align}
Here, the $a(i,j), b(i,k)$ are known constants and could be forced to be positive if needed. Moreover, $a(i,j)$ and $a(j,i)$ need not take the same value. I am looking to compute this with a machine and as fast as possible. How can I go about this? Good references are also appreciated, but should ideally be very specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) problem.  I hope this link helps.
Your version can be written as $Q^tAQ+B^tQ$, subject to $Q\geq0$ and $1^tQ=1$.
Here, A is the matrix formed by $a(i,j)$, and $B$ is the vector formed by $B_i=\sum_{k=1}^N b(i,k)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Wikipedia does not display an entry under your link. I also know that it is a quadratic programming problem, but it also has a particular form I hope one can exploit for computational gains.